# it's possible to implement fragment in app build with angular nativescript?

Tags: fragment, nativescript

I'm building app with nativescript angular, and i have some data in firebase store, i wanto something like fragment fra android app, is that possible ?
my data is some lessons and timestamp where i wanto so show data date and the lesson for that day, and then i wanto to swipe to the right and next date and the appropriate lessons for that day. All that data is saved in the firebsae store.

this is my home component where the schedule wiil be

```
<ns-action-bar title="{{title}}" [showBackButton]="false"></ns-action-bar>
```

```
<StackLayout class="body">

    <Label text="Velkommen"> </Label>
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <Label [text]="user?.firstName " class="username"></Label>
        <Label [text]="user?.lastName "></Label>
        <Label *ngIf="myClass" [text]="homeservice.getYearGrade(myClass)"></Label>

    </StackLayout>


</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Every `Page` in your application is already a Fragment with NativeScript Activity, so yes for Fragments. But I'm unsure how you like to use fragment here. May be you are looking for something like [Page](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-pager), share a template for each page but data will be different based on date, you can swipe left or right?

Comment: Yes it is right. I want to do that